# Xamarin HybridWebView navigate to page in cache folder

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

I've want to make a xamarin forms webview app that downloads a webpage (the app itself) then displays it. Before downloading I show a local login page that will invoke the app once the user submits the form. The local page will be inside the app package, the downloaded page will be downloaded to a location the app can store data (CommenApplicationData in this uwp example, but I have to use the documents folder on iOS).

I've already made a .NET Core library that downloads, unpacks and supports script commands that the webpage inside the webview uses. The main entry class to this library is called: BroadsheetInterface and it accepts the messages from the webview (BroadsheetInterface.RunCommand) and uses a interface to make callbacks to the webview(RunJavascript).

To show the local "login page" and downloaded "app page" or "launcher page", I use the HybridWebView example from Xamarin. I then modified the platform specific hybridwebview to do it's own navigation like this:

```
// IWebView is a interface that is used for the BroadsheetInterface can do callbacks 
// to this control
public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView>, IWebView 
{
    // The pointer to the current "BroadsheetInterface", a class that has all logic of 
    // the webpage inside the webview
    public BroadsheetInterface_Helper BroadsheetInterface { get; set; }

    // The standard call to setup the webview to a local page, I use this call to show 
    // the login page.
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            SetNativeControl(new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView());
        }
        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            Control.NavigationCompleted -= OnWebViewNavigationCompleted;
            Control.ScriptNotify -= OnWebViewScriptNotify;
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            Control.NavigationCompleted += OnWebViewNavigationCompleted;
            Control.ScriptNotify += OnWebViewScriptNotify;

            LoadLoginPage();                
        }
    }

    // Once the local page has been loaded I setup the library (note the "this" 
    // parameter), then check if the user has checked the "remember login" checkbox 
    // last time he or she logged in.
    void OnWebViewNavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.IsSuccess)
        {
            BroadsheetInterface = new BroadsheetInterface_Helper(this);
            BroadsheetInterface.Browser_SetLogin();
        }
    }

    // If the Javascript inside the webview calls the app, the command will be passed 
    // into the BroadsheetInterface to be processed. 
    void OnWebViewScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        BroadsheetInterface.RunCommand(e.Value);
    }

    // If the library want to call the webpage inside the webview, it will call 
    // this function
    public async void RunJavascript(string script)
    {
        await Control.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { script });
    }

    // Show the login page
    public void LoadLoginPage()
    {
        Control.Source = new Uri(string.Format("ms-appx-web:///Content//{0}", Element.Uri));
    }

    // Show the launcher page
    public void LoadLauncherPage()
    {
        // The location of the launcher page
        var fullname = BroadsheetInterface.AccountHelper.CurrentAccount.GetLauncherPage().FullName;
        // fullname = "C:\Users\wille\AppData\Local\Packages\a05728a3-841f-4ef2-8f13-f1dbf39590a0_tbz3402trp7yy\LocalState\ProgramData\Launcher\willem\index.html"

        // Convert the path to a url
        var url = "file:///" + fullname.Replace("\\", "/");
        // url = "file:///C:/Users/wille/AppData/Local/Packages/a05728a3-841f-4ef2-8f13-f1dbf39590a0_tbz3402trp7yy/LocalState/ProgramData/Launcher/willem/index.html"

        // Set it to the webview
        Control.Source = new Uri(url);
        // DOESN'T WORK :(
    }

    // This is called from the library to get the location where to store 
    // the launcher page
    public string GetCacheFolder()
    {
        return Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
    }
}
```

Now the app runs, I can login and when I submit, it start downloading the files. After the files have been downloaded I want to set the webview to show the launcher page that has been downloaded. So I call the "LoadLauncherPage()" function but, it doesn't change to the downloaded page. It's like setting the "Source" parameter doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found it out myself.

I guess it's not allowed to set the Source property of the WebView to a "file:///" url. So I came across this solution:

```
// Show the launcher page
public void LoadLauncherPage()
{
    Uri uri = Control.BuildLocalStreamUri("Launcher", "/index.html");
    Control.NavigateToLocalStreamUri(uri, new StreamResolver(BroadsheetInterface));
}

// Resolver for mapping the files
public class StreamResolver : IUriToStreamResolver
{
    private BroadsheetInterface_Helper broadsheetInterface;

    public StreamResolver(BroadsheetInterface_Helper broadsheetInterface)
    {
        this.broadsheetInterface = broadsheetInterface;
    }

    public IAsyncOperation<IInputStream> UriToStreamAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        if (uri == null) throw new Exception();
        return GetContent(uri.AbsolutePath).AsAsyncOperation();
    }
    private async Task<IInputStream> GetContent(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            string fullname = broadsheetInterface.AccountHelper.CurrentAccount.RootFolder.FullName + path.Replace("/", "\\");
            StorageFile f = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(fullname);
            IRandomAccessStream stream = await f.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            return stream;
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw new Exception("Invalid path"); }
    }
}
```